# Vectors must be the same lengths

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot angles against time. Here the code:

```
clear all
close all
params.t0   = 0;     % start time of simulation
params.tend = 10;   % end time
params.m=2^8; %number of steps in each Brownian path
params.deltat=params.tend/params.m; % time increment for each Brownian path
params.R=4; % integer number to obtain EM stepsize from Brownian path stepsize 
params.dt = params.R*params.deltat; %0.01;    % time increment for both EM and ode45
params.D=0.001; % diffusion constant 
deltat= params.tend/params.m; % time increment for each Brownian path
params.D=0.1; %diffsuion 
params.R=4;
params.dt =  params.R*params.deltat; 
theta0=pi*rand(1);
phi0=2*pi*rand(1);
P_initial=[theta0;phi0];

[theta,phi]=difusion_SDE(params);
plot([0:params.dt:params.tend],[theta0,theta],'--*') 
hold on
plot([0:params.dt:params.tend],[phi0,phi],'--*')
```

and the function file:

```
function [theta,phi]=difusion_SDE(params)

dW=sqrt(params.deltat)*randn(2,params.m);
 theta0=pi*rand(1);
 phi0=2*pi*rand(1);
P_initial=[ theta0; phi0];

L =  params.m/ params.R;
pem=zeros(2,L);
Ang_rescale=zeros(2,L);
Ptemp=P_initial;

for j=1:L
   Winc = sum(dW(:,[ params.R*(j-1)+1: params.R*j]),2);
   theta=Ptemp(1); 
   phi=Ptemp(2);  

   A=[  params.D.*cot(theta);...
       0]; 

   B=[sqrt(params.D)  0 ;...
      0 sqrt(params.D)./sin(theta) ];  

   Ptemp=Ptemp+ params.dt*A+B*Winc;
   pem(1,j)=Ptemp(1); 
   pem(2,j)=Ptemp(2);


Ang_rescale(1,j)=mod(pem(1,j),pi);  
Ang_rescale(2,j)=mod(pem(2,j),2*pi);    
theta= Ang_rescale(1,j);
phi=Ang_rescale(2,j);
end
```

When I run the code, I got this message error 
    Error using plot
    Vectors must be the same lengths.
I appreciate any help to solve this error

Comment: What are the sizes of the input to your `plot` function?

Comment: You need to show at what line the error occurs

Comment: There are a number of tools/functions which can help debugging your code. The [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html), [size](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html), [length](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html), [numel](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html)... Just pick your favorite and go for it. It is not funny, I know that, but this is how the harsh reality works. In case you are going to work a lot with Matlab in the future I strongly suggest learning the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plot(x,y), x and y need to be of the same length. [0:params.dt:params.tend], is of size 65, [theta0,theta] of size 2. difusion_SDE needs to output a vector of size 65 with intermediate results for each timestep instead of just the end result.